# Connection Refused in Mysql Server [2002]

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I currently have a basic server at Digital Ocean with the following configurations: **1GB Ram, 25GB SSD, 1 vCpu, Ubuntu 20.04**.

Although I have a relatively average amount of hits on my server, from time to time mysql stops working and I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Checking `mysql status`, I receive the message:

```html
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Fri 2021-11-05 10:42:18 UTC; 3 days ago
    Process: 227847 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 227855 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 227855 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"

Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 18.
Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Nov 05 10:42:18 XYZ systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I've tried a few things already, like changing the database communication commands, or changing the port from 8888 to 8889, and none of them solved my problem.

**SOLUTION:** The only thing that solves this problem is logging into the server and restarting mysql with the commands:

```
$ sudo service stop mysql
$ sudo service start mysql
```

The problem is that this is a passing solution, and it doesn't seem to solve the cause of the problem itself. Maybe this problem is only happening because of "lack of memory", since my server has only 1GB of Ram and an average amount of monthly accesses (3000 accesses).

Assuming this problem is due to "lack of memory", how can I confirm this? (Will I have to restart mysql every time this problem happens for the rest of my life?)

Comment: Thes question is not about programming related issue as the error message indicated in the title is the result of your mysql server being down. You need to figure out why this happens. Questions about operating databases are to be asked on the dba sister site of SO. I would also rename this question as you need to fix the restart problem. I would also contact your hosting provider as they may know what's going on.

Comment: You should check the Mysql logs and try journalctl also - systemctl only shows the last few entries but there should be more.

Comment: The stackexchange site for [database administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) would be a better place for this question.